# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages | can partial views have page models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview, razor-pages

I have a partial view called _Subscribe.cshtml

Is it okay for partial views to have a page model _Subscribe.cshtml.cs?

I want to allow people who visit my website to be able to subscribe to keep up-to-date with any changes to my website.

The subscribe form will be in the _Subscribe.cshtml and this partial view will be called in the footer in the _Layout.cshtml.

This is because I don't want the subscribe view to be accessed directly through the url.

Is this a good or bad approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure can, and I personally feel it's a perfectly sound approach!  If you do specify a model for a partial, however, it is REQUIRED!  Some folks like to hang a child model object off their main page model, then pass it into the partial, but I like being explicit about it.

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("Shared/_MobileBackNav", new MobileBackNavOptions { ShowBackButton = false })
```